# jQuery: establishing a relation between check-all checkbox and the child checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

This is a standard scenario where I have a check-all checkbox which will check or uncheck a group of checkboxes based on its own state.

```
$('.checkall').on('click', function () {
    $(this)
        .closest('#grid')
        .find('#tblId')
        .find(':checkbox')
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

If the child checkboxes are modified individually, I manipulate the state of the check-all checkbox like this:

```
$('.child-checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($('.child-checkbox:checked').length == $('.child-checkbox').length) {
        $('.checkall').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('.checkall').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

I am happy that this is working as expected, but I want to know if I can combine these two snippets in such a way that the relation between check-all checkbox and the child checkboxes are managed in one snippet.

Comment: you can catch all checkboxes clicks, and check the class in one function, but the way you did it is cleaner IMHO

Comment: Why are you using `.closest()` and `.find()` to select elements by id? If you know the id you can just use `$('#tblId')`, assuming you have valid html where id is unique... I'd fix that before worrying about combining your two functions.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I may have introduced some redundancy for the sake of this question, but in reality the child checkboxes were in a separate location than the checkall checkbox and it necessitated the use of `.closest()` which I found to be the faster solution at the time. Also, I have little to no control over the HTML, sadly.

Comment: @RoyiMindel: Thanks! I am kind of storming through jQuery learning and implementing things as I need them, so I have written the code in the cleaner way possible first and then come here to find out if minimization is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be nicely combined to one snippet, but from what I can see it can be simplified to

```
var $all = $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
    $childs.prop('checked', this.checked);
});
var $children = $('.child-checkbox').change(function () {
    $all.prop('checked', $children.not(':checked').length != 0);
});
```

If you are still looking for a single handler then try

```
$('.checkall, .child-checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is('.checkall')) {
        $('.child-checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    } else {
        $('.checkall').prop('checked', $children.not(':checked').length != 0);
    }
})
```

Comment: I love your first snippet. It is so easy on the eyes. Grouping selectors is something I didn't know all these days, which is seemingly basic.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this
 see whether it would help

```
   $('.checkall,.child-checkbox')on('click', function () {
    if(this==".checkall"){
        $(this)
            .closest('#grid')
            .find('#tblId')
            .find(':checkbox')
            .prop('checked', this.checked);
    }else{
      if ($('.child-checkbox:checked').length == $('.child-checkbox').length) {
            $('.checkall').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $('.checkall').prop('checked', false);
        }

    }
    });
```